# Data Migration from On-Prem DB to Cloud

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-migration

Need inputs on the below requirement where there is a need to migrate the data from databases like
SQL Server, Teradata, Oracle-DB to  AWS-S3 first to create a data lake.

Specifically looking for suggestions on :
--> Which services of AWS can be used to achieve this, as in to migrate the data models along with the data.
--> Any tools which can help expedite this migration process.

Regards,
Somen Swain

Comment: Hi for our Oracle to Snowflake migration, we have used Attunity's replicate tool , like Attunity you have a tool called Strim and there are many in the market.

Comment: There are several products you can evaluate - Qlik Replicate, HVR (FiveTran), Matillion, to name a few popular ones.  AWS you can use DMS, Data Synch ... but you'll likely need to create the target database separately in order to populate.